# regex expression not recognising the other lines

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a regex which I would like to match a couple of things:
Here is a link to the examples and the code which I have started but for errors which I cannot determine in my regex is not recognising some lines: http://regex101.com/r/oL4bB5/1

The string examples:

eg1: `Tommy Berry`

eg2: `Ms Winona Costin (a3/47kg)`

eg3: `Ms Kathy O'Hara`

End result using findall in python:

eg1: ['Tommy Berry']

eg2: ['Ms','Winona Costin', '3', '47']

eg3: ['Ms', 'Kathy O'Hara']

As you can see, I want to isolate the `Ms` at the beginning of the string, the digits within the parenthesis and maintain the full name.
I appreciate the help, thanks!

---

**EDIT**

The name may contain numbers and special characters such as `'-. etc.`:
eg: `Samuel L. Jackson-Pitt`

Comment: What's your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
^(Ms)?\s*([\w '-]+)(?= \(|$)(?: *\(\D*(\d+)\D*(\d+)[^\n]*)?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oL4bB5/4)

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """Brodie Loy (a3/53kg)
Hugh Bowman
Ms Winona Costin (a3/47kg)
James McDonald
Ms Kathy O'Hara"""
>>> m = re.findall(r"^(Ms)?\s*([\w '-]+)(?= \(|$)(?: *\(\D*(\d+)\D*(\d+)[^\n]*)?$", s, re.M)
>>> m
[('', 'Brodie Loy', '3', '53'), ('', 'Hugh Bowman', '', ''), ('Ms', 'Winona Costin', '3', '47'), ('', 'James McDonald', '', ''), ('Ms', "Kathy O'Hara", '', '')]
>>> [tuple(s for s in tup if s) for tup in m]
[('Brodie Loy', '3', '53'), ('Hugh Bowman',), ('Ms', 'Winona Costin', '3', '47'), ('James McDonald',), ('Ms', "Kathy O'Hara")]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is: ([demo](http://regex101.com/r/tH1gB9/2))

```
^(Ms)?([\w '-]+)(?:.*?(\d+)\/(\d+))?
```

Remember to use `re.MULTILINE`.